# How to compare the z values of all row with same x and y values efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with columns x, y, z, and b. For each x and y pair (describing pixels), I want to compare the z values and set b to true for all pixels if all z values only differ within a certain threshold (e.g. 0.3). If the z values differ more than the threshold for some pixels, then only set b to true for the pixels with the smallest z value (within the threshold), and set b to false for the others (above the threshold).

I think, I might use the `groupby` function of pandas, like

```
df[['x','y','z','b']].groupby(['x','y'])
```

to get all sets with same x and y. But how can I apply a function then to perform the upcoming comparison and so on? Or are there some numpy functions that could do that?

Example:

I have the following table (as dataframe)

```
   x         y              z
-----------------------------
1124       922      78.601423
1124       922      78.602461
1124       922      95.140586
1123       922      78.603544
1123       922      78.604400
1123       922      78.605449
1123       922      78.606395
1123       922      87.247255
1123       922      87.234766
1123       922      78.609117
1123       922      78.610156
...
```

What I want to have, would look like

```
   x         y              z      b
------------------------------------
1124       922      78.601423   true
1124       922      78.602461   true
1124       922      95.140586  false
1123       922      78.603544   true
1123       922      78.604400   true
1123       922      78.605449   true
1123       922      78.606395   true
1123       922      87.247255  false
1123       922      87.234766  false
1123       922      78.609117   true
1123       922      78.610156   true
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use:

```
s=df.groupby(['x','y'])['z'].transform('min')
#if you need subtract based on the first value and not min use :
#s=df.groupby(['x','y'])['z'].transform('first')
df=df.assign(b=df.z.eq(s)|(df['z']-s).le(0.3))
```

---

```
       x      y          z      b
0   1124  922.0  78.601423   True
1   1124  922.0  78.602461   True
2   1124  922.0  95.140586  False
3   1123  922.0  78.603544   True
4   1123  922.0  78.604400   True
5   1123  922.0  78.605449   True
6   1123  922.0  78.606395   True
7   1123  922.0  87.247255  False
8   1123  922.0  87.234766  False
9   1123  922.0  78.609117   True
10  1123  922.0  78.610156   True
```

Comment: I think what jezrael means that the z seriesmight have the following values 78, 90,90.01,90.02,90.03. In this case, the logic mentioned by you will not work for jezrael

Comment: @AnantGupta Thank you, so in this case the expected output should be? just confirming if i didnt get thequestion right

Comment: Thanks, it looks good! I am just testing. And you assumed correctly with the min value.

Comment: The answer should be False, True, False, False,False as per the logic mentioned